# AEM HTL dynamic property name

Tags: aem, sightly

Is there any way in HTL to use dynamic property name something like this

```
${class.map['prefix' + item.name]}
```

Comment: This will not work. What do you want to do? This looks like a ReactJS programmer tries HTL. The AEM/Sling approach is, that the data/content is prepared in a Sling Model (Java), and then just rendered with a very limited HTL templating language. This approach guarantees, that only valid HTML is rendered, and stops Cross-Site-Scripting.  (But still, HTL lacks a lot of features it could have - while being secure.) So please tell us, what you want to do? The answer is properly a Java Sling Model.

Comment: I have map of key values that is playing role of dictionary (`className.mapName`) and then getter for another map on which I run HTL list function and base on value like to select correct value from dictionary. I could set in my object for loop new property with dictionary value but it seems like unnecessary duplication of data.

Comment: Please add some sample data and a better/more detailed explanation to your question. Maybe then we can help you. Sorry, I do not really understand what you want to reach. (PS: Your technical approach is not working. But if we understand the underlying functional problem, then we could propose an alternative technical solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of [data-sly-set](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2212-set) to do a concatenation before the rendering:

```
<sly data-sly-set.appended="prefix${item.name}">${appended}
```